# How to validate empty text input and stop the display of NaN?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm using the following HTML code to display a table:

```
<table border='1' id='markstbl'>
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th class='questionth'>Question No.</th>
    <th class='answermarksth'>Marks per Answer</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    <tr class="questiontd">
    <td class="questionnumtd" name="numQuestion" rowspan="2">1 <input type="hidden" name="q1_ans_org" class="q1_ans_org" value="5"><input type="hidden" name="q1_ans" class="q1_ans"></td>
    <td class="answermarkstd">
    <input class="individualMarks q1_mark_0"  q_group="1" name="answerMarks[]" id="individualtext" type="text" />
    </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="questiontd">
    <td class="answermarkstd">
    <input class="individualMarks q1_mark_0"  q_group="1" name="answerMarks[]" id="individualtext" type="text" />
    </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="questiontd">
    <td class="questionnumtd" name="numQuestion" rowspan="1">2 <input type="hidden" name="q2_ans_org" class="q2_ans_org" value="5"><input type="hidden" name="q2_ans" class="q2_ans"></td>
    <td class="answermarkstd">
    <input class="individualMarks q2_mark_0"  q_group="1" name="answerMarks[]" id="individualtext" type="text" />
    </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Below is what the table looks like:

```
Question No.     Marks Per Answer         
    1            (blank text input)       
                 (blank text input)
    2            (blank text input)
```

As you can see question 1 contains 2 text inputs while question 2 contains 1 text input.

Now what I want to do with the code below is validate for any empty text inputs.

```
function validation() {

    var alertValidation = "";
    var _qid = "";
    var _msg = "";

    $("[class*='q']").each(function(i) {  
    var questions = parseInt($("[class*=q" + i + "_qnum]").text());
    var marks = parseInt($("[class*=q" + i + "_ans_text]").text()); 
    var txtinput = $("[class*=q" + i + "_mark]").val(); 
    _qid = questions;
    _msg = "You have errors on Question Number: " + _qid + "\n";


if (txtinput == '' || txtinput == null) {
    alertValidation += "\n\u2022 You have not entered in a value for all the Indivdiaul Marks textbox\n";
}    

            if (alertValidation != "") {
                return false; //Stop the each loop 
            }

        });


    if (alertValidation != "") {
        alert(_msg + alertValidation);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

The problems is that in the alert it does not display the question number `_qid` as that it displays it as NaN and also even though no text input is blank, it still displays an alert stating that not all inputs contains a value.

My quqestion is how do I display the question number and how do I properly check for a empty text input correct so that if text input is empty, then it displays the alert with the correct question number and if all text inputs contains a value, then it does not display a validation?

I like to say that the `_qid` does work for when I include the code below for another validation check in the `validation()` function which is placed exactly below the if statement checking for empty text input:

```
if(marks < '0')
{

 alertValidation = "Your Total Marks Remaining does not equal 0 \n\n\u2022 You Need To Remove " + Math.abs(marks) +  " Marks";   
}

        else if(marks > '0')
{

 alertValidation = "Your Total Marks Remaining does not equal 0 \n\n\u2022 You Have " + marks +  " Marks Remaining";   
}
```

When the alert appears for the above validations, it displays the question number in the alert. It just doesn't display it when I validate empty text input? Is it because I may have multiple text inputs within a question so I might need to include another foreach() loop in the code for empty text input?

BELOW IS WHAT THE FULL `Validation()` CODE LOOKS LIKE:

```
function validation() {

    var alertValidation = "";
    var _qid = "";
    var _msg = "";

    $("[class*='q']").each(function(i) {  
    var questions = parseInt($("[class*=q" + i + "_qnum]").text());
    var marks = parseInt($("[class*=q" + i + "_ans_text]").text()); 
    var txtinput = $("[class*=q" + i + "_mark]").val(); 
    _qid = questions;
    _msg = "You have errors on Question Number: " + _qid + "\n";


if (txtinput == '' || txtinput == null) {
    alertValidation += "\n\u2022 You have not entered in a value for all the Indivdiaul Marks textbox\n";
}    


if(marks < '0')
{

 alertValidation = "Your Total Marks Remaining does not equal 0 \n\n\u2022 You Need To Remove " + Math.abs(marks) +  " Marks";   
}

        else if(marks > '0')
{

 alertValidation = "Your Total Marks Remaining does not equal 0 \n\n\u2022 You Have " + marks +  " Marks Remaining";   
}

            if (alertValidation != "") {
                return false; //Stop the each loop 
            }

        });


    if (alertValidation != "") {
        alert(_msg + alertValidation);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Below are examples of what the validation messages look like:

**Marks Higher than 0 validation:**

```
You have errors on Question Number: 1
Your Total Marks Remaining does not equal 0 

• You Have NaN Marks Remaining
```

**Marks Less than 0 validation:**

```
You have errors on Question Number: 2
Your Total Marks Remaining does not equal 0 

• You Need To Remove NaN Marks
```

**Empty Text input validation:**

```
You have errors on Question Number: NaN

• You have not entered in a value for all the Indivdiaul Marks textbox
```

As you can see above alert is the only one which doesn't display question number

Thanks

Comment: This makes no sense `marks < '0'`. `NaN` probably coming from there. Have you tried linting your code?

Comment: Yeah my code was linked, I just seperated it in the question, I will display what the full jquery code looks like under the FULL JQUERY CODE section

Comment: I mean _linting_ as in using a Lint tool such as [jsHint](http://www.jshint.com/) to check for errors in your JS code.

Comment: @elclanrs I tried comparing txtinput to null or '' by using === instead of == but that means it doesn't check for empty text input. There are no errors in error console so there is no javascript error. I did some linting but there are some warnings I disagree with because I have obviously not include html code with the javascript for liniting

Comment: @elclanrs I have created a jsfiddle so you can see the problem for yourself and test anytheories you may have (http://jsfiddle.net/cbyJD/4/)